# How to graph with an arrow?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

I want to draw the following pic in latex. Please help.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{tikz}  
\begin{document}  
  
\begin{tikzpicture}  
  [scale=.9,auto=center,every node/.style={circle,fill=blue!20}] % here, node/.style is the style pre-defined, that will be the default layout of all the nodes. You can also create different forms for different nodes.  
    
  \node (a1) at (1,2) {1};  
  \node (a2) at (2,5)  {2}; % These all are the points where we want to locate the vertices. You can create your diagram first on a rough paper or graph paper; then, through the points, you can create the layout. Through the use of paper, it will be effortless for you to draw the diagram on Latex.  
  \node (a3) at (3,7)  {3};  
  \node (a4) at (3,2.5) {4};  
  
  \draw (a1) -- (a2); % these are the straight lines from one vertex to another  
  \draw (a2) -- (a3);  
  \draw (a2) -- (a4);  
  \draw (a1) -- (a3);
    \draw (a1) -- (a4);
\end{tikzpicture}  
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is my suggestion. I use a style `n` with a parameter for nodes with different colors. The `turn` key is for creating coordinates `O5t`, `O6t` that joining with a dashed line.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}  
\usepackage{tikz}  
\begin{document}  
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{
n/.style={circle,fill=#1,inner sep=1.5pt},
n/.default=cyan
}    
\path
(0,0)    node[n=red] (q)  {} node[below=1mm] {$q$}
(1.5,0)  node[n]     (O6) {} node[below right] {$O_6$} 
(.5,2)   node[n]     (O5) {} node[above right] {$O_5$}
(-1.5,0) node[n]     (O4) {} node[below=1mm] {$O_4$} 
(-4,0)   node[n]     (O3) {} node[below left] {$O_3$} 
(-3,2)   node[n]     (O2) {} node[above=2mm] {$O_2$}
(-5,2.5) node[n]     (O1) {} node[above left] {$O_1$} 
;
\draw[cyan,very thick] (O1)--(O2)--(O3)--(O4)--(O2)--(O5) (O4)--(O5)--(O6);
\foreach \p/\q in {O1/O2,O2/O5,O5/O6} {
\path 
(\q)--(\p)--([turn]-90:.2) coordinate (t\p)
(\p)--(\q)--([turn]90:.2)  coordinate (t\q);
\draw[cyan,thick,densely dashed,-latex,shorten >=2pt,shorten <=2pt] (t\p)--(t\q);
}
\end{tikzpicture}  
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. But it seems complicated especially the way to draw arrow lines. Is there any easy way to draw directed dotted lines between two nodes?

Comment: @Rma The code given by BlackMild answers your question `\draw[cyan,thick,densely dashed,-latex,shorten >=1pt,shorten <=1pt] (O5t)--(O6t);`

Comment: I have added few more vertices but it is not working

Comment: @Rma How complicated the code is? I always try to code as simple as possible ^^I added an revision.

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture} [
arr/.style = {-Straight Barb, dashed, shorten >=4mm, shorten <=4mm},
dot/.style = {circle,fill=#1, inner sep=2pt, outer sep=0pt,
              node contents={}},
dot/.default = cyan,
 every edge/.append style = {draw=cyan, arr},
every label/.append style = {text=black},
xs/.style = {xshift=1mm},
ys/.style = {yshift=1mm}
                        ]
\draw[cyan, semithick]
    (0,3) node (a1) [dot, label=$O_1$] --
    (2,2) node (a2) [dot, label=$O_4$] --
    (5,2) node (a5) [dot, label=$O_5$] --
    (6,0) node (a6) [dot, label=below:$O_6$]

    (0,0) node (a3) [dot, label=below:$O_3$] --
    (3,0) node (a4) [dot, label=below:$O_4$] --
    (a5)
    
    (a3) -- (a2) -- (a4);
\path (5,0) node[dot=red, label=below:$q$]; 
\draw   ([ys] a1.north) edge ([ys] a2.north)
        ([ys] a2.north) edge ([ys] a5.north)
        ([xs] a5.east)  edge ([xs] a6.east);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```